# How to implement the AND command in a Google apps function correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that checks if a cell in column 7 is checked.

```
if (r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "x")
```

How do I write this to check if EITHER column 7 OR Column 8 are checked?

```
if (r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "x") OR if (r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "x")
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

`OR` is represented with `||`

So if you want `(7 OR 8) AND x` , just write :

```
if ((r.getColumn() == 7 || r.getColumn() == 8) && r.getValue() == "x")
```

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox So AND is represented by &&, right? I just realized I need the AND command instead. 
TASK: If there is NO "x" in both collumns, 7 and 8, then (...)
so i tried: if ((r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getColumn() == 8) && r.getValue() == "")

But it doesent work :(

Comment: That would be the expected result (not working): getColumn() would never return true for two separate values it is 7 OR 8, 7 || 8 not 7 && 8. To ensure the value is NOT x in both column 7 AND 8, you need to rearrange you logic slightly: `if ((r.getColumn() === 7 && r.getValue !== "x") && (r.getColumn() === 7 && r.getValue !== "x")) { ... } else { ... }` There is no *OR* in the logic here just in the semantics. You want no x in either 7 nor 8, so you need to check that it isn't in 7 *AND* isn't in 8

Comment: @TobiasH - no offense but your question was a bit unclear, I guess Jonathon just managed to decode what you had in mind (I hope so), I didn't, I just gave a translation of the code you provided... Your comment brought some light on this though ;-)

Comment: @Serge you are absolutely right, I was not precise: even in the last comment I made a mistake. forget about the x, I want to ensure that both collums are empty, so I will try if ((r.getColumn() === 7 && r.getValue !== "") && (r.getColumn() === 7 && r.getValue !== "")) { ... } else { ... }

Comment: @Jonathon I think your second Number was supposed to be 8 instead of 7...? So I tried this  `((r.getColumn() === 8 && r.getValue !== "") && (r.getColumn() === 7 && r.getValue !== ""))`   But no success :(

Comment: you've changed what you are asking for - are you looking for no x in either 7 or 8 or are you lookign to find an x in either 7 or 8 - its a different question !== means not equal to so !=="" means not blank - based on you answer to Serge i think you want to change that to ===""